# order of evaluation of || and && in c

Tags: c

If the precedence of && is greater than that of ||, shouldn't this code evaluate --b && ++c first, and thus the output should be 1 2 4 11. But here it seems to be short circuited to give 1 2 5 10. Please help!

```
int x;
int a=1,b=5,c=10;
x=a++||--b&&++c;
printf("%d %d %d %d\n",x,a,b,c);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> shouldn't this code evaluate --b && ++c first

**No** Operator precedence doesn't affect evaluation order. It just means that

```
a++||--b&&++c
```

is equilvalent to

```
a++||(--b&&++c)
```

so it's still `a++` that is evaluated first, and thus short-circuits the statement.

Comment: So how do we know when to put the brackets and when not?

Comment: @Ashwyn a good rule of thum is to put brackets wherever the intent is not clear. In this case, it's not a matter of brackets, IMO it's pretty clear what happens.

Comment: @Ashwyn I think you're missing the point. You're right to assume that && is tighter than ||. But the expression still evaluates from left to right.

Comment: Ok! gotcha, thanx! I was making a mistake evaluating the more precedent operator first. It's pretty clear now. Thanx!

Comment: @Ashwyn: Note that `||` and `&&` are two of the very few operators that *guarantee* left-to-right evaluation (the others are `?:`, function-call `()`, and the comma operators); in all other cases, evaluation order is *unspecified*. For an expression like `a + b * c`, the compiler may evaluate each of `a`, `b`, or `c` in any order.

Answer (score 2):

The precedence of `&&` is higher, which means it binds tighter to the things on the left and right of it than `||`. So that expression is equivalent to

```
a++ || (--b && ++c)
```

`||` only evaluates the thing on the right if the expression on the left evaluates to non-0. Since a is `1`, only `a++` will be evaluated, and `b` will not be decremented and `c` will not be incremented.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `&&` has higher precedence, but that only determines the *grouping* of the operands, not the *order* of evaluation. The base operation here is `||`, which guarantees its right side is not evaluated if the left is true, regardless of what operations are on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

There are two concepts at work here

1. Operator associativity
2. <del>Compiler optimization</del> Short Circuiting

In C, || operator is left associative. As a result, a++ will be evaluated first.
Since the left side is TRUE, <del>compiler optimization</del> short-circuiting will make sure that the right side of the || is not evaluated because it will not change the result of the expression.

Comment: It has nothing to do with optimizations or compilers. Short-circuiting is standard defined behavior.

Comment: You are right in the sense that compiler optimizations are optional whereas short circuiting is not optional. But intuitively this is an optimization. I will edit the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[Lazy evaluation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LazyEvaluation).

`--b && ++c` is not evaluated at all.